# jquery div not showing more them on user profile

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have been working on this code for a while and I am finally stumped and cannot figure out what the heck to do to get this issue fixed.

I have a jquery code that works beautifully for the get profile, but when i need to return the values in a div, it only shows the first profile of the user, but if a user posts more then once on the blog, it will not show the profile information.  I have tried to append more information for each profile div to be different, but its still not working.

Here is the jQuery code for the GET user profile and return response.

```
function showUser(str)
  {
var profileDiv = document.getElementById("profile_"+ str);
    if (str=="")
{
  return;
  }

   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
 else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
 {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
  profileDiv.innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
  xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
  }
```

Also here is the PHP script that i am using to pass the information

```
"<div id=\"info\" onmouseover=\"showUser(" .$blogrow['id_user'].")\"><imgalign= \"left\" style=\"vertical-align:top;\" class=\"imgb\" height=\"41\" width=\"41\"  src=\"profilepics/".$blogrow['pic']."\" />".$blogrow['author']." <br>".$blogrow['timestamp']."<br></div><br>";
    echo "</div>";
```

here is the div part as well that stores the information

```
 echo "<div id=\"txtHint\"><div id=\"profile_".$blogrow['id_user']."\"></div></div>";
```

Comment: Is the site available/can you give the url?

Comment: also you could throw a debugger in your code and see how it differs between the first mouse over and all the following

Comment: I am running this on Firefox, one of the issues is when it is looking for the profile div, it shows that there are 2 of them the same.  and it is only taking the first div and using it.  The site is in non-productive status, and is up and running, the link is [link](http://www.exercisevideolibrary.com) and you can log in with username: demo pass: demo  You will have to go to the blog to see this and it is under the second heading there that says "Adding new features"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem relies on your HTML markup, which is invalid. Element ids must be unique in a HTML page but I see a lot of repeated ids such as `#info`, `#theDiv`, `#txtHint` and `#profile_X`

A quick fix for your problem would be to change all those and any other repeating ids to a class and then use the ajax code provided by @Rohan Kumar but using a class selector to append the content to every mention of the user in the page

```
function showUser(str)
{
    $.ajax({
       url:'getuser.php',
       data:{q:str},
       type:'GET',
       success:function(data){
           $(".profile_"+ str).html(data);
       }
    });
}
```

This is definitely not the most efficient or elegant solution but I think it would work. If you were to try and improve your code I would suggest binding all divs of class `.info` to a mouseenter handler, using data-attributes to get the user id and maybe maintaining a list of the profiles retrieved so you don't end up making redundant calls to your php

Comment: this is my code for the hover

     `<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('.theLinks').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).closest('.content3').next('.theDiv').fadeIn();
    },
    function () {
        $(this).closest('.content3').next('.theDiv').hide();
});
});//]]>  

</script>`

Comment: So are you still having the problem? did you fix all the repeating ids and updated your showUser function?

Comment: changing the div to a class worked beautifully.  It is now showing all profiles with the same information!!!!! Thanks for that!

Comment: If you want to see it in action:  [Open Website](http://www.exercisevideolibrary.com) username: demo pass: demo

thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Using `$.ajax` it will more simple like,

```
function showUser(str)
{
    $.ajax({
       url:'getuser.php',
       data:{q:str},
       type:'GET',
       success:function(data){
          $("#profile_"+ str).html(data);
       }
    });
}
```

**But,** before this you need to add any `version` of **jQuery**

Comment: Thanks for that, it does the same as the other top code but the same issue is still there, it cannot display the user if they comment more then one time on the blog...